# Walkie talkie antenna

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, wavelength, antennas

how is it possible that the antennas of the walkie talkies are so small, if the frequencies they receive have wavelengths of more than 30 cm? Maybe the why's are quarter wave antennas? and for pulsed signals the same is true?

Comment: see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/449947/

Comment: A good source for information about antenna design: http://www.arrl.org/arrl-antenna-book