Why length of antenna is $\lambda/4$?
I have read in my book under communication systems topic that the minimum length of antenna required for communication is wavelength/4 without any explanation. What is the reason for this? Why is only a quarter of a wavelength chosen? I cannot understand.

It is because of resonance.
See Dipole antenna - Vertical (monopole) antennas

either you read it wrong or you read a wrong book, any size can be used for communications, see the Hertz dipole; any AM radio operating in the ~200 to 450m  wavelength range uses antennas to receive the signal with antennas about 10cm long.

for more detail see my answer to this question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/449947/why-are-longwave-radio-towers-so-tall
